# Parse JSON strings into R list

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I have my JSON file and I want to parse it in a list. I wonder if I can parse only the lines with specific string in it? For example

```
{"app":15c,"device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":15b,"device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":15a,"device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
```

and I want to parse only the lines that have `"app":15a`
I want to have a list with the last line! (The problem is I have a lot of data and my computer can't parse the whole JSON file, and I need only one app)

Comment: Hi Smasell, can you provide an example of the JSON you want to parse, the desired output, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: The most robust way would be to parse everything and then filter the list. Filtering before parsing is much more tedious as the formatting of the JSON  might potentially vary.

Comment: @MrMobster Yeah I now it! I've edited the question! Is it possible without parsing the whole file?

Comment: `15c` (etc) can't be bare. they are strings

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to optimize the following but it might not be necessary in your case:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame()
jsonlite::stream_in(file("/tmp/apps.json"), 
                    function(x) { 
                        df <<- bind_rows(df, filter(x, app=="15b"))
                     })
```

I made a file that looks like:

```
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15c","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15b","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
{"app":"15a","device_carrier":"Verizon Wireless"}
```

Run that code and you get:

```
df
## # A tibble: 13 × 2
##      app   device_carrier
##    <chr>            <chr>
## 1    15b Verizon Wireless
## 2    15b Verizon Wireless
## 3    15b Verizon Wireless
## 4    15b Verizon Wireless
## 5    15b Verizon Wireless
## 6    15b Verizon Wireless
## 7    15b Verizon Wireless
## 8    15b Verizon Wireless
## 9    15b Verizon Wireless
## 10   15b Verizon Wireless
## 11   15b Verizon Wireless
## 12   15b Verizon Wireless
## 13   15b Verizon Wireless
```